# Keep a value from a dropdown list after posting

Tags: php, session, post, drop-down-menu

I am trying to write a 3-part drop down list selection menu. The second drop down list is dependent on data from the first list and the third drop down is dependent on data from the second. I have tried using post to do this, but each time the form is submitted it blanks out the data from the previous down box and if I try to use a session variable to store the data, it too is reset when the form is submit.

here is my code:

```
    //get a list of course subjects from the database
$subjects = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT subject FROM db.course;");
echo "<select name='getSubject' onchange='this.form.submit()'>";
echo '<option value="" style="display:none;" ></option>';
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($subjects) )
{
   echo "<option value='" . $row['subject'] . "' >". $row['subject'] ."</option>"; //creates drop down list of subjects

}
echo "</select> &nbsp;";

$selectedSubject = $_POST['getSubject'];
echo $selectedSubject;

//get a list of course titles from the database, based on subject chosen
$courses = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT title FROM db.course WHERE subject = '$selectedSubject';");
echo "<select name = 'getTitle' style='width:500px;' onchange='this.form.submit()'>";
echo '<option value="" style="display:none;"></option>';
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($courses) )
{
   echo "<option value='" . $row['title'] . "' >". $row['title'] ."</option>"; //creates a drop down list of course titles

}
echo "</select> &nbsp;";

$selectedTitle = $_POST['getTitle'];
echo "$selectedTitle";


//get a list of section numbers from the database, based on course chosen
$sections = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT section FROM db.course WHERE title = '$selectedTitle';");
echo "<select name = 'getSection' style='width:200px;' onchange='this.form.submit()'>";
echo '<option value="" style="display:none;"></option>';
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sections) )
{
   echo "<option value='" . $row['section'] . "' >". $row['section'] ."</option>"; //creates drop down list of course sections

   }
echo "</select>";

$selectedSection = $_POST['getSection'];


$course = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT title, subject, section FROM db.course WHERE subject = '$selectedSubject';");


?>
```

How can I keep the data from getSubject intact after a selection from getTitle and getSection is made? after the final drop down box is selected I would like it to print all three selections below the menu.I have been struggling with this for several hours now and am not sure how much more abuse my keyboard can take.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition, inside the loop where you print the options, that uses the `selected` argument if that is the option that is selected on submit.

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($subjects)) {
   if($_POST['getSubject'] == $row['subject']) $s = " selected"; else $s = "";
   echo "<option value='{$row['subject']}'$s>{$row['subject']}</option>";
}

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($courses)) {
   if($_POST['getTitle'] == $row['title']) $s = " selected"; else $s = "";
   echo "<option value='{$row['title']}'$s>{$row['title']}</option>";
}

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sections)) {
   if($_POST['getSection'] == $row['section']) $s = " selected"; else $s = "";
   echo "<option value='{$row['section']}'$s>{$row['section']}</option>";
}
```

Hope this helps.